# R has an uncountable number of distinct dense subsets.

Tags: general-topology

Does someone know how to prove this?

Let S and T be non-empty subsets of a topological space (X, τ) with S ⊆ T.
(iii) Hence show that if S is dense in X, then T is dense in X.

(iv) Using (iii) show that R has an uncountable number of distinct dense subsets.

I just wanna prove the fourth item using the result of the third.

I tried to do it by contradiction, but i don't know what exactly i have to do!

Comment: You should know at least one dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which has uncountable complement. Use this and (iii) to build a bunch of distinct dense subsets!

Comment: You can toss any irrational into the set of rationals.

Comment: I still haven't figured out how to do it with the tips you said.
@MorganRogers

Comment: I didn't understand your hint, @DavidMitra. Can you explain it more?

Comment: One dense set is $\Bbb Q$ (the set of rational numbers). Another is $\Bbb Q\cup\{\sqrt2\}$. How many others can you find?

Comment: @DavidMitra:  this shows that there are $2^{\mathfrak c}$ dense subsets of $\Bbb R$

Comment: Woooow, @DavidMitra, that is fantastic! I really understood what you're doing. I really appreciate your kindness. So we can put how many irrational number that we want, and by that third item, that set we've constructed will always be a dense set as well. But, how can I construct a "rigorous" prove to show that the number of those sets is uncountable?

Comment: There is an obvious bijection between the collection of sets I hinted at (just adding one irrational) and the set of irrationals.

Comment: All right! Thank you, @DavidMitra, your are amazing! I really appreciate your attention. Have a nice week!

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Without using (iii) it is even easier. Each set $\mathbb R \setminus \{x \}$ with $x \in \mathbb R$ is dense. But (iii) allows you to show that there are uncountably many *countable* dense subsets.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was found in the comments. Here is a concluding proof.

We know that $|\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}|=|\mathbb{R}|$, so $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})|=|\mathcal{P}\mathbb{R}|$.

By (iii) and because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, for any $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ the set $\mathbb{Q}\cup U$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.
The function from
$$
\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})\rightarrow\{\text{dense subsets of $\mathbb{R}$}\}
$$
defined by
$$
U\mapsto\mathbb{Q}\cup U
$$
is well-defined by (iii), and it is clearly injective.
So there are at least $|\mathcal{P}\mathbb{R}|$ (usually denoted $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$) dense subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.
There are, of course, at most $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ dense subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.
So there are exactly $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ dense subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.
The cardinal $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}>\aleph_0$ is uncountable.